# Computation of String Tension in Lattice QCD

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, standard-model, quantum-chromodynamics, lattice-model

There is a quantity called String Tension in lattice QCD calculation.

> **How is this quantity (String Tension) defined and computed in Lattice QCD? Are there some useful formulas to define it both in the continuum as well as on the lattice?**

The attached figure shows an example about the result of computations in gauge theories :

[image]

Thanks for the answer, if you can help please!

Answer (score 4):

Quick answer: The string tension $\sigma$ as shown in that plot (which looks like an older version of Fig. 11 in arXiv:1004.3206) is the dimension-2 coefficient of the linear term in the static potential $V(r)$ (the energy of two infinitely heavy probes separated by spatial distance $r$).  So one computes $V(r)$, typically from the exponential decay of rectangular $r\times T$ Wilson loops oriented along the temporal direction, $W(r,T) \propto e^{-V(r)\cdot T}$, and then fits $V(r) = -\frac{C}{r} + A + \sigma r$ to determine $\sigma$.

The stuff above is in continuum language, implicitly working in "lattice units" where the dimensionful lattice spacing is set to $a=1$.  Non-zero lattice spacing leads to discretization artifacts in the predictions for the dimensionless combination $a^2 \sigma$, which are removed by extrapolating $a \to 0$.  One can play games with lattice perturbation theory to reduce these artifacts.

This is one of the simplest non-trivial calculations one can do in lattice gauge theory, so it should be covered comprehensively in the standard textbooks/lecture notes.  Silvia Necco's PhD thesis, [hep-lat/0306005](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-lat/0306005), might be a good starting point.

Comment: Why is it called string tension though? Because it's associated with $r$? I always thought this terminology came from string theory

Comment: Yeah, I believe the terminology has its roots in 'hadronic string theory' --- attempts to model hadrons as strings in the late '60s and early '70s, pre-QCD.  Stretching those hadronic strings (increasing $r$) increased their energy $\propto r$, with the proportionality factor being the string tension.  A motivation for this stringy approach was that eventually the string would 'break', explaining $1\to2$ hadronic decays.  In QCD, this was reinterpreted in terms of an effective string action, with the 'string' being a gluon flux tube.  The brief review hep-lat/0511023 might have more info.